# admob not showing in app (emulator or device)

Tags: android, admob

I try to add admob, but I have some problem with it.
This is the code for the test, it looks ok:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, pubID);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID"); 
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And this code with pubID

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, pubID);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I can't understand what's wrong... Just admob is not showing. That's all...
Can anyone help me with this problem?
Regards, Peter.

**UPD** oh sorry. Also all settings set in manifest file( permission , and adsense activity)

**upd**
all response from admob in logcat :

```
01-11 21:49:31.805: I/Ads(363): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
01-11 21:49:33.405: I/Ads(363): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1,"slotname":"a14f0d9ca22bc53","u_w":320,"msid":"activityM.activity.com","simulator":1,"cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.3.1","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.activityM.activity.com","hl":"en","u_h":480,"u_audio":4});</script></head><body></body></html>
01-11 21:49:41.714: I/Ads(363): Received ad url: <"url": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&u_sd=1&slotname=a14f0d9ca22bc53&u_w=320&msid=activityM.activity.com&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.3.1&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&cipa=0&format=320x50_mb&net=ed&app_name=1.android.activityM.activity.com&hl=en&u_h=480&u_audio=4&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&ex=1&client_sdk=1&pto=0&jsv=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
01-11 21:49:42.255: I/Ads(363): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

That's all what i found in ddms.

Comment: Do you have entry in manifest.xml? did you check logcat? Are you seeing any entries in logcat that  you are getting response from Admob?

Comment: Is your ad space properly placed in the layout? Also does your application have permission for internet connection?

Comment: all permission and settings is ok.. because test version of admob worked perfectly.

Comment: it takes a while to receive/show the very first admob response, up to 2 minutes from their official website, but could be more.

Comment: so guys ??? it's normal problem ??

Comment: I had given answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686221/admob-ads-are-not-showing-up-in-emulator/57686663#57686663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tells all.

`01-11 21:49:42.255: I/Ads(363): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)`

This has happened to me sometimes.  They just don't have any ads to send out at the moment for whatever reason.  They will eventually pop up when they have something in their inventory.  Nothing to worry about, just keep checking and it will eventually pop up.

Comment: so... u mean it's normal ?? just need wait.. and maybe than i see my admob in my app ? just need wait ? (1 minute.. 1 hour.. or 1 day :)  )

Comment: If it is a newly created site/app on AdMob, it can take multiple requests and some time (can be on the magnitude of a few days I think) for that site id to start serving live ads.  This is normal behavior.

Comment: Also if your app hasn't fetched an ad in 24 hours, it takes 2 minutes to receive an ad initially.

Comment: hey, how long it's can be ? I see this stupid adsense only one per 1-5 days :(. It's very big problem for me.. always have this error "on Failed to receive Ad) :(((

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean but if your app goes 24 hours without an ad fetch such as nobody using it, then it takes at least 2 mins to be able to fetch one

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. But I think the Google Admob FAQ has the answer
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#whynoads

Quote:

> I think I've implemented everything correctly, so why am I not seeing
>   ads?
>
> While maintaining the highest possible fill rate is one of our top
>   priorities, we may not always have an ad available for every ad
>   request. This can be especially common during development, when ad
>   requests are typically made infrequently from a small number of users
>   and devices. When apps are newly registered on AdMob it may also take
>   some time and several requests before impressions are consistently
>   delivered. Developers generally see more consistent results once they
>   have released their app and ad requests arrive more frequently from a
>   more diverse user base.
>
> Note: The very first time AdMob sees your publisher ID it may take up
>   to two minutes to receive an ad, and this initial two minute lag will
>   recur every time the app goes unused for 24 hours.

And yes, the admob reports showing low request count.