# AdMob ads are not showing up in emulator

Tags: android, admob

I am integration AdMob ads in my application I am running y application in emulator and in admob i have set device id to emulator.But even after ads are not showing up in emulator.

Below is my code:

**XML**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_nam_sub"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="MY_ADUNIT_ID"
            >

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**JAVA**

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "@string/app_id");

adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("@string/ad_unit_id");

MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

AdRequest adRequest = new 
AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>

    .....

   <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="@string/app_id"/>

</application>
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: are you saying it works on an actual device ?

Comment: I haven't tested on actual device yet I am debugging application on emulator.

Comment: Add a listener on `AdRequest.Builder` to check the error code, then look at error codes from documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest

Answer (score 1):

Here is simplest way for banner ad.

In Manifest:

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>
```

In XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

In Your First Activity:

```
AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
        try {
            MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
```

In Activity Where ad will load:

```
val adRequest: AdRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
                ad_view.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Code is in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving ad id & adSize in both XML and JAVA file which is not correct.

Comment: When I am removing ad id & adSize from Java file it is showing error . The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.

Comment: In my another answer given below. Follow that and implement it.